# Next.js (REACT) Not firing "onChange" event on first "uncheck" on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I have made a grid of "checkboxes" for permissions within the component. For some reason, it doesn't trigger the first "onChange" event if the action is unchecking a checkbox, which loads its state by default from the server. Guidance on what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated, thank you so much!

**UPDATE**: Using checked instead of "defaultChecked" seems to fix the issue, however, then I come up with this error:

> "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: ...."

Here's the Component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import api from "../../lib/api";
import useForm from "../../lib/useForm";

export default function PermissionSelector({ user, permissions }) {
    let initialState = permissions;

    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(null);

    let { inputs, handleChange, resetForm, setForm } = useForm(initialState);

    if (!loaded) {
        setForm(permissions);
        setLoaded(true);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        setError(false);
        setSuccess(false);

        console.log(inputs);

        await api()
            .put(`/user-permissions/${user.id}`, inputs)
            .then((res) => setSuccess("Permissions have been updated!"))
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err.status === 422) {
                    setError(err.data.message);
                }
            });

        setLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <style global jsx>
                {`
                    .permissions {
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }
                    .permissions li {
                        list-style: none;
                        display: block;
                        float: left;
                        width: 50%;
                    }

                    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                        .permissions li {
                            width: 25%;
                        }
                    }
                `}
            </style>
            {success && <div className="alert alert-success">{success}</div>}
            {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
            <Form className="form-primary" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <ul className="permissions">
                    {loaded &&
                        Object.keys(permissions).map((permission) => (
                            <li key={permission}>
                                <Form.Check
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    id={permission}
                                    label={permission.split("permissions.")[1]}
                                    name={permission}
                                    defaultChecked={inputs[permission]}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    custom
                                />
                            </li>
                        ))}
                </ul>

                <div className="btn-container">
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn-submit"
                        disabled={loading}
                    >
                        {loading && "Updating..."}
                        {!loading && "Update"}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here's the useForm:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useForm(initial = {}) {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initial);

    const initialValues = Object.values(initial).join("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setInputs(initial);
    }, [initialValues]);

    function handleChange(e) {
        let { value, name, type } = e.target;

        console.log(type, name, value);

        if (type === "checkbox") {
            console.log(e.target.checked);
            value = e.target.checked;
        }

        if (type === "number") {
            value = parseInt(value);
        }

        if (type === "file") {
            [value] = e.target.files;
        }

        setInputs({
            ...inputs,
            [name]: value,
        });
    }

    function resetForm() {
        setInputs(initial);
    }

    function setForm(inputs) {
        setInputs(inputs);
    }

    function clearForm() {
        const blankState = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(inputs).map(([key, value]) => [key, ""])
        );
        setInputs(blankState);
    }

    return {
        inputs,
        handleChange,
        resetForm,
        clearForm,
        setForm,
    };
}
```

Comment: did you fix it? I have the exact same problem